# Snakemake: creating directories and files anywhere while using singularity

Tags: python, snakemake

Whenever I use snakemake with singularity and would like create a directory or file, I run into read-only errors if I try to write outside of the snakemake directory.

For example, if my rule contains the following:

```py
container:
    docker://some_image
shell:
    "touch ~/hello.txt"
```

then everything runs fine. `hello.txt` is created inside the snakemake directory. However if my `touch` command tries to create a file outside of the snakemake directory:

```py
container:
    docker://some_image
shell:
    "touch /home/user/hello.txt"
```

Then I get the following error:

```
touch: cannot touch '/home/user/hello.txt': Read-only file system
```

Is there anyway to give snakemake the ability to create files anywhere it wants when using singularity?

Answer (score 1):

Singularity by [default mounts certain directories](https://apptainer.org/user-docs/master/bind_paths_and_mounts.html?highlight=home%20default#system-defined-bind-paths) including user's home directory. In your first command (`touch ~/hello.txt`), file gets written to home directory, where singularity has read/write permissions. However in your second command (`touch /home/user/hello.txt`), singularity doesn't have read/write access to `/home/user/`; you will need to bind that path manually using [singularity's `--bind`](https://apptainer.org/user-docs/master/bind_paths_and_mounts.html?highlight=home%20default#user-defined-bind-paths) and supply it to [snakemake via `--singularity-args`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#SINGULARITY).

So the snakemake command would look something like

```
snakemake --use-singularity --singularity-args "--bind /home/user/"
```

Comment: For some reason, the home directory (`~`) is actually the snakemake repo directory. Do you have any idea why that's the case? More specifically, when the command is `touch ~/hello.txt`, the `hello.txt` file is created in the snakemake repo directory instead of my home directory. Moreover, `$HOME` did not appear to be bound, because then `/home/user/` would have worked.

Comment: That's a strange behavior of `~`. (1) What are the output of `echo ~` and `echo $HOME` in your system? 
(2) If you create those files without using container, do they get created in the location you expect them to? (3) Please show us the snakemake command used.

Comment: The output of `echo ~` and `$HOME` are both correct (`/home/user`). Only when I run the pipeline does `~` switch to the snakemake repo. Somehow snakemake is interpreting `~` as the snakemake repo.

Command used: `snakemake -c2 --configfile /home/user/path/to/config.yaml --use-conda --use-singularity`

Comment: It may be a good idea to add `echo ~` to the the shell command in your snakemake rule and see what it resolves to.

Comment: It binds to the snakemake repo directory. I can't access anything else outside of it.